# Is it possible to configure embbeded Dictionaries using C#.NET4.0 and Windsor Castle

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dictionary, castle-windsor, ioc-container

In C#.NET4.0 with Windsor castle IoC Framework v2.5.3,
is it possible to configure embbeded Dictionaries ?

I tried some configuration (see below) without success.

Here the Components.xml file

```
<component
   id="MyComponent"
   service="MyAssembly.IMyInterface,MyAssembly"
   type="MyAssembly.MyClass,MyAssembly">
  <parameters>
    <MyProperty>#{MyComplexDictionaryProperty}</MyProperty>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

Here the ComponentsProperties.xml file:

```
<MyComplexDictionaryProperty>
  <Dictionary
    keyType="MyAssembly.MyEnum1,MyAssembly"
    valueType="... ??? ...">
    <Entry key="MyEnum1Value1">
      <Dictionary
        keyType="MyAssembly.MyEnum2,MyAssembly"
        valueType="System.Int32, mscorlib">
        <Entry key="MyEnum2Value1">1</Entry>
      </Dictionary>
    </Entry>
  </Dictionary>
</MyComplexDictionaryProperty>
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: I think if you're having dictionaries of dictionaries Windsor's config is the least of your problems. Seems to me like you're abusing primitives

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that done before.  According to the [documentation on XML configuration](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx), the hash mark (#) syntax is used for referencing another property in the config file in the format "property.id".  Are you sure you're using it correctly?